# Very simple ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-applications

I'm making a web app. I run this function with jquery 1.11.2 in index.html:

```
$.ajax("http://localhost/index.html")
    .done(function () {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("fail");
    });
```

It works fine. I try it with another file:

```
$.ajax("http://localhost/online.html")
    .done(function () {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("fail");
    });
```

I have this error message:

```
GET http://localhost/online.html net::ERR_FAILED
```

online.html is in the same folder, it contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Picture Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Why it doesn't work ?

Thanks.

Comment: Dunno. What does the net console show?

Comment: What do you want to see exactly ? Here network tab: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2rp32on.jpg

Comment: What web server are you running?

Comment: Across all browsers, or just chrome? If you change the name, then what? Any anti-virus/etc extensions installed?

Comment: Check if you can get page http://localhost/online.html in the browser.

Comment: This script checks the loading of the page in which it is inserted [$.ajax(this)] and doesn't work if you want check another page [$.ajax("another_page.html")]

Comment: yes I can load localhost/online.html in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a manifest.mf to build a web app which work even if device hasn't access to internet.

If I add online.html in manifest.mf it works, I don't understand why. Now idk how to check if the browser is online or offline, the request will always success with this method.

So I found answer to my original question, thanks for help.

**Edit:** Still work if I put online.html in NETWORK list in manifest.mf, but it looks like the browser still store it in cache.

**Edit 2:** Finally working fine if I request a .php page instead of requesting .html contents.

Comment: That this was an app and not just a web page would have been valuable information to include :/

Comment: Yea sorry I'm beginner in web technologies so I'm a little bit lost ;)

Comment: Please edit your question to include this detail about the app, otherwise your question will be closed.